# Flask | JINJA 2: render_template_string() with macro imported in context

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am looking to make macros available inside of the articles for my flask blog. When the body of my blog changes I run the following code to render the body into HTML:

```
target.body_html = bleach.linkify(bleach.clean(render_template_string(value),tags=allowed_tags, attributes=allowed_attr, strip=True))
```

render_template_string(value) is the part I'm concerned about. To use a macro inside of the template string (value), every single string has to include the following in order for me to use the macros from this file in the article body:

```
{% import "includes/macros.html.j2" as macros %}
```

This would not be reasonable to ensure that writers have access to the macros that I write in all of their articles. Is there any way to pass that argument via the render_template_string() function so that it doesn't have to be defined in every string? Or to otherwise create a template that the string is rendered inside of? Something like the following:

```
render_template_string(string,macros=function_to_import_macros("includes/macros.html.j2"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there does not appear to be a solution to pass an entire macros template as context, get_template_attribute does appear to allow you to pass individual macros one at a time. Example:

includes/macros.html.j2:

```
{% macro hello() %}Hello!{% endmacro %}
{% macro hello_with_name(name) %}Hello, {{ name }}!{% endmacro %}
```

Template rendering code:

```
hello = get_template_attribute("includes/macros.html.j2","hello")
hello_with_name = get_template_attribute("includes/macros.html.j2","hello_with_name")
return render_template("index.html", hello=hello,hello_with_name=hello_with_name)
```

index.html:

```
{{ hello() }}
{{ hello_with_name("Bob") }}
```

This solution will allow for adding individual macros to the context while rendering a template or template_string and can even be added to the global context via this method. If anyone knows how to add an entire template full of macros, that'd rock, but this allows the basic needed functionality.